# Fetch upcomming Expiry Date Notifications And Get Date In SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design

I am currently working on a Query For Notification Serivces. i want Fetch Upcoming Expiry Date Notification. My Table is :
[image]

Comment: What result do you expect?

Comment: Dear  Wojciech Jasiński,,, I want Fetch emp_name Upcomming Expiry Date Like Raj Jain Lic_expDate today

Comment: @AsheeshYadav Can you please tell me which field `Upcomming Expiry Date` you want ? 

Like for example `Lic_expDate` Or `HazVal_expDate` Or `PsReport_expDate`.

Comment: And I want free beer for the rest of my life. That being said, I doubt I will get it just because I demand it. What have your tried so far? Please take the [introductory tour](http://www.stackoverflow.com/tour). You might want to read [How do I ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), which enhances the probability for getting a useful answer _drastically_. You might find [ESR](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eric_S._Raymond)'s excellent essay [How To Ask Questions The Smart Way](http://catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html) helpful, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the Current day expiry dates, use this query:

```
select emp_name, LIC_expDate from querydata where LIC_expDate = CURDATE();
```

To get list of all expiry dates from today and upcoming dates, use this query:

```
select emp_name, LIC_expDate from querydata where LIC_expDate >= CURDATE() order by LIC_expDate asc;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM querydata WHERE manfacexp_date > date(now());
```